# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended In Spring batch Item Writer

Tags: spring, oracle

I am writing one spring batch based application in which i have to write a consolidated xml file data into multiple tables of database.

```
bean id="mysqlItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
      <value>

             <![CDATA[  
              INSERT INTO LEASE (LEASE_ID, CONTRACT_TYPE, CONTRACT_NUMBER, LEASE_AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, CREATE_DATE, REGISTER_DATE)
           VALUES ( :leaseId, :contractType, :contactNumber, :leaseAmount, :description, :leaseCreateDate, :leaseUpdateDate)

                  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER  (CUSTOMER_ID ,FIRST_NAME,  LAST_NAME,  SURNAME, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, RECORD_CODE,
             SOURCE_SYSTEM,  BIRTH_DATE,CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE,ADDRESS,STREET,HOUSE_NUMBER,
             STATE,  POSTAL_CODE,  COUNTRY_CODE )
              VALUES ( :customerId , :firstname, :lastName ,:surname, :customerNumber, :recordCode, :SourceSystem,
              :birthDate, :leaseCreateDate, :leaseUpdateDate, :address, :houseNumber, :city, :state, :postalcode,
              :countryCode)

            ]]>
          </value>
```

In the above code when only one SQL statement is there it is working fine but for two insert statements it is not working fine. It is giving the error as 
    "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" .
When i am inserting ; after first insert statement it is showing the same error
I am not able to resolve this..

Comment: You can't send more than one SQL statement with a single `executeUpdate()` call in JDBC.

Comment: So how should i proceed in such scenario?any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try wrapping your 2 statements inside a PL/SQL anonymous block (Make sure you don't forget any of the required semi colons).

```
begin
    insert into ...;
    insert into ...;
end;
```

Technically, it should then be treated as a single statement and should work.

```
bean id="mysqlItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
      <value>

             <![CDATA[
              begin  
              INSERT INTO LEASE (LEASE_ID, CONTRACT_TYPE, CONTRACT_NUMBER, LEASE_AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, CREATE_DATE, REGISTER_DATE)
           VALUES ( :leaseId, :contractType, :contactNumber, :leaseAmount, :description, :leaseCreateDate, :leaseUpdateDate);

                  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER  (CUSTOMER_ID ,FIRST_NAME,  LAST_NAME,  SURNAME, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, RECORD_CODE,
             SOURCE_SYSTEM,  BIRTH_DATE,CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE,ADDRESS,STREET,HOUSE_NUMBER,
             STATE,  POSTAL_CODE,  COUNTRY_CODE )
              VALUES ( :customerId , :firstname, :lastName ,:surname, :customerNumber, :recordCode, :SourceSystem,
              :birthDate, :leaseCreateDate, :leaseUpdateDate, :address, :houseNumber, :city, :state, :postalcode,
              :countryCode);
              end;
            ]]>
      </value>
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer but I tried this and it seems PL/SQL cannot be used in item writer. It is trying to convert into sql prepared statement and throwing bad SQL grammar error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good description of the issue here:
http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/formatted-sql-enddelimiter-issue

I suggest adding the "/" to see if that works in combination with

endDelimiter:/ or using splitStatement:false